# Add a dependency to gradle.build from CLI

Tags: android, node.js, gradle, build.gradle

many dependency management tools have very convenient cli helpers for saving new dependencies in the configuration files.

For instance, `npm install --save express` will save the info about `express` dependency to the project's `package.json` file.

I wonder if there is an equivalent in the gradle world? In particular, I'm looking for a way to add `fabric` dependency to my `build.gradle` from cli.

Here the changes that needs to be done to my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```